# Snappy on Beaglebone Black or Green

Tags: ubuntu-core, beagleboard

Is there a flasher image available for snappy? I would like to run it from the eMMC rather than an sd card.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Follow the instructions as provided on the following page

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/

Basically insert your SD card, make sure it is unmounted. Make sure you know what block device SD car is with `lsblk` and `sudo blkid` commands.

The three commands you will need are:

```
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-bbb.img.xz
```

and

```
unxz -c ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-bbb.img.xz | sudo dd of=/dev/sdX bs=32M
```

And

```
sync
```

Finally take out your SD card and take beaglebone for the spin. I personally would connect it with ethernet cable attatched to the router, find out ip and ssh into it. Default username and password are both `ubuntu`

Couple things to remember:

- snappy filesystem is by default mounted read-only. If had to remount to make changes in  `/etc/`
- you may have to use `wpa_supplicant` , there is no `network-manager` on snappy.

Comment: So will this actually write it to eMMC. I was able to get it to boot from the SD card but it didn't appear to write it to the flash. The other thing is, I currently have an older BBB with only 2gb if eMMC. Is it still possible to flash this device with Snappy ?

Comment: I'm also looking at this issue - I can get snappy to install and run on an SD card.

But I can't get it to flash my eMMC. Can you advise in a bit more detail?

Thanks!

Comment: @DanielD that is slightly beyond my knowledge